# Is there a way to get a "short path" from a full path in java?

Tags: java, java-8

I want to pull out a lower level path from the full path. The best way to explain this is an example:

This is my full path:

```
/home/users/<username>/documents/projects/file
```

And I have another path just to my documents directory:

```
/home/users/<username>/documents/
```

How can I get out a path or string object that is:

```
/projects/file
```

Comment: Have you checked [`Path.relativize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize-java.nio.file.Path-)?

Comment: Yes, but this just gives me `../..` instead of the actual name.

Comment: Swap the order/arguments.

Comment: Yep, I was just about to edit my comment. I was being dumb, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answering based on [Progman's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/286934/progman) comment.

```
Path docPath = /home/users/<username>/documents/;
Path fullPath = /home/users/<username>/documents/projects/file;

docPath.relativize(docPath.resolve(fullPath));
```